# Remove Navigation Bar from React-Native-Navigation v2?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation-v2

How to disable navigation bar for a specific screen in React-Nativa-Navigation V2?

Answer (score 1):

For a specific component not showing topbar it can be done by putting

```
topBar: {  visible: false }
```

in the `options` of `component` like so

```
Navigation.setRoot({
      root: {
        stack: {
          id: "App",
          children: [
            {
              component: {
                name: "rci.Login",
                options: {
                  topBar: {
                    visible: false
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    });
```

And also if it need to be set at the stack level so that no screen in the stack shows topbar we can do that by setting

```
 options: {
    topBar: {
      visible: false
    }
  },
```

inside the stack. The whole code looks like

```
Navigation.setRoot({
root: {
 stack: {
  options: {
    topBar: {
      visible: false
    }
  },
  children: [
    {
      component: {
        name: 'navigation.playground.TextScreen',
        passProps: {
          text: 'This is tab 1',
          myFunction: () => 'Hello from a function!',
        }
      }
    },
    {
      component: {
        name: 'navigation.playground.TextScreen',
        passProps: {
          text: 'This is tab 2',
        }
      }
    }
   ]
  }
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best option will be setting static options inside your component:

```
export default class YourComponent extends Component {
  static get options() {
    return {
      topBar: {
        visible: false,
        animate: false
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Notice that you can toggle the topBar visibility change animation.

Comment: Thanks, Would Use this as well. But why do think this is a better option than the one used by me?

Comment: Because it is always a possibility that you will want to use this screen in a different flow.. in such case you will have to duplicate this code. It is just more explicit for the screen

Comment: Okay. If we want the screen without navigation bars in all flows this is a good option. Otherwise, if the visibility of the navigation bar is scenario specific then the other one is the better option. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `StackNavigator`, you need to set `header` to `null` on a given screen:

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null,
  };

  ...
}

export default createStackNavigator({
  Home: HomeScreen
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. The correct way to do as of `@react-navigation/native 5.1.3` seems to be this `headerShown: false`

```
<NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Login">
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Login"
      component={LoginScreen}
      options={{ title: "Login Screen", headerShown: false }}
    />
    {..other stuff..}
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```